# JSON Data is not populated into the Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, c#-4.0

I have the following code in my js file. When i alerted and checked the value of **key**, its being coming from JSON response, but when i checked my **val**, its shown as **[object object].** So i tried using **val.value**, the value comes to be **undefined.**

**FYI:** I am getting the correct response from my controller through Json, i have checked it, **all i want to know is how to populate text value into the dropdown.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    BindTitle();
});

function BindTitle() {
    $.ajax({
        "url": "/Admin/GetTitleList/",
        "type": "get",
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function (data) {
            var appenddata;
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                appenddata += "<option value = '" + key + " '>" + val.text + " </option>";
            });
            $("#TitleId").html(appenddata);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you know data structure (concrete items of JSON object) of incoming data? if not, try console.log() instead of alert() and edit it into your post so I can help you more

Comment: where does console.log() will make a log, i mean how to use it, i new to it, please help

Comment: It will make log into your browser console. You can access it with pressing usually F12 key.

Comment: Attached a screenshot @OutOfSpaceHoneyBadger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of building dropdown wont work on ie8
try

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/GetTitleList/",
    type: "GET"
    success: function (data) {
        var items = $('#id of your dropdown');
        items.empty();
        $.each(data, function (i, drddata) {
            items.append($('<option/>', { value: drddata.Value, html: drddata.Text
        });
    });
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```